# how to add result from function to another function and display in DIV ID html with java

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps

I want to take the result of variable price below at no.1, and add it (counter) to the function totalprice in counter, and display it in a Div ID in html!

no.1]

```
function startLineRd3(price) {
  select("line_b");
  var color = getColorIndus3(false);
  var line = new GPolyline([], color);
  startDrawing(line, "Rd. lvl3 " + (++lineCounter_), function() {
    var cell = this;
    var len = line.getLength();
    **var price= ((Math.round(len / 10) / 100) * 1);**
    cell.innerHTML = (Math.round(len / 10) / 100) + "km" + " " + "Price: " + price +     "Mil";
  }, color);
```

}

no.2]

```
function totalprice(Counter) {
    var Counter= 0;
    document.getElementById('totalprice').innerHTML = Counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript variables are limited in scope.  You're defining var price inside of your startDrawing call, which means that you have to be inside the startDrawing call to access it.  Instead, define it more globally, and then just set it inside of the startDrawing call.  If you have multiple prices, you may want an array of them, so that you can sum each time something changes.  If they're not going to change, then just define Counter globally, and add price to it every time startLineRd3 gets called

At least, this is the solution to what I *think* your problem is.  If that's not the problem you have, please try to be more clear about what you are currently doing successfully, and where your difficulty lies.

Oh, and the fact that var price is the same as input parameter price is a bit of a problem.  You should give them different names.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Javascript has nothing to do with Java. I know the name is misleading - it was designed to be that way.

Second, you're declaring `Counter` in function 2 twice. If you're taking it as an argument then you don't need to re-declare it, and doing so will override the first declaration.

So, if you delete the line `var Counter= 0;`, then you can just call function 2 from function 1. So the first function becomes:

```
function startLineRd3(price) {
  select("line_b");
  var color = getColorIndus3(false);
  var line = new GPolyline([], color);
  startDrawing(line, "Rd. lvl3 " + (++lineCounter_), function() {
    var cell = this;
    var len = line.getLength();
    var price= ((Math.round(len / 10) / 100) * 1);
    totalprice(price);
    cell.innerHTML = (Math.round(len / 10) / 100) + "km" + " " + "Price: " + price +     "Mil";
  }, color);
}
```

Comment: Fixed the misuse of java tag.  Thanks.